# Get the Headers of Requests in selenium at C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, monitoring

I have a selenium scraper that open the site and login in to it. The site has been written by react or react native and the data of the page get from API.
I want when the selenium open the browser and login to it capture the Get and Post Request too.
I want to get the specific header from one of the API request.

I have tried many way such as browsermobproxy (not compatible with .net 6 ) and other ways but no one can't solve my problem.
I have tried this too :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");

// Create a new ChromeDriver object.
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

// Navigate to the target website.
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://test.com/");

// Get the network requests.
List<NetworkRequest> requests = driver.GetNetworkRequests();

// Print the request details to the console.
foreach (NetworkRequest request in requests)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Request URL: {request.Url}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Request Method: {request.Method}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Request Status Code: {request.StatusCode}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Request Headers:");
    foreach (var header in request.Headers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"  {header.Key}: {header.Value}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

// Close the browser.
driver.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use devtools with chrome driver

```
using var driver = new ChromeDriver();

IDevTools devTools = driver;
DevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
await session.Domains.Network.EnableNetwork();

session.DevToolsEventReceived += OnDevToolsEventReceived;

void OnDevToolsEventReceived(object? sender, DevToolsEventReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EventName == "requestWillBeSentExtraInfo")
    {
        var requestHeaders = e.EventData["headers"];
    }
    if (e.EventName == "responseReceivedExtraInfo")
    {
        var responseHeaders = e.EventData["headers"];
    }  
}

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I Use this and it solve my problem

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.SetLoggingPreference("performance", LogLevel.All);
options.AddArgument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://test.com/");
var performanceLogs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog("performance");
// Find Specific Request
var jsonText = performanceLogs.Where(p => p.Message.Contains("some of the api url or the header name")).FirstOrDefault();
//Header
string pattern = "\"The Header Name\":\"([^\"]+)\"";
Match match = Regex.Match(jsonText.ToString(), pattern);
string Header= "";
if (match.Success)
{
Header= match.Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine("Header: " + Header);
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("Header not found.");
}
driver.Quit();
```